# AngularJS passing bootstrap button group value to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button group and I want to pass the value of the selected button back to my controller but it isn't working, it just returns undefined...

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <button type="button" ng-model="activeCustomer" value="active" ng-click="getVal()" class="btn btn-default">Active</button>
        <button type="button" ng-model="activeCustomer" value="inactive" ng-click="getVal()" class="btn btn-default">Inactive</button>
        <button type="button" ng-model="activeCustomer" value="all" ng-click="getVal()" class="btn btn-default">All</button>

        {{change}}
    </div>
```

**Controller** :

```
aap=angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl',["$scope",function($scope){
  //set the radio buttons
    $scope.change='the data';
    $scope.getVal=function(){
        console.log($scope.change);
        console.log($scope.activeCustomer);
        $scope.change=$scope.activeCustomer;
    }
}]);
```

however if I change the code from `<button type="button"` to `<input type="radio"` it works! Any ideas? Thanks

http://plnkr.co/edit/Hfu7EGQ05hA59Sgty29H?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the working code -

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <button type="button" ng-model="activeCustomer" value="active" ng-click="getVal($event)" class="btn btn-default">Active</button>
        <button type="button" ng-model="activeCustomer" value="inactive" ng-click="getVal($event)" class="btn btn-default">Inactive</button>
        <button type="button" ng-model="activeCustomer" value="all" ng-click="getVal($event)" class="btn btn-default">All</button>

        {{change}}
    </div>


<script>
aap=angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl',["$scope",function($scope){
  //set the radio buttons
    $scope.change='the data';
    $scope.getVal=function(active){
        console.log($scope.change);
        console.log(active.currentTarget.value);
        $scope.change=active.currentTarget.value;
    }
}]);


</script>
```

You need to pass the $event for each button and access it in controller. Then after you can change the value.

Here is the plunker:-

http://plnkr.co/edit/wkzJ46zRoczkMPomzEok?p=preview

Comment: always welcome.. glad to know that my answer solved your problem.. :) :)

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <button type="button"
                    value="active"
                    ng-click="getVal('active')"
                    class="btn btn-default">
                Active
            </button>
            <button type="button"
                    value="inactive" 
                    ng-click="getVal('inactive')"
                    class="btn btn-default">
                Inactive
            </button>
            <button type="button"
                    value="all" 
                    ng-click="getVal('all')"
                    class="btn btn-default">
                 All
            </button>
 </div>
```

**Controller** :

```
.controller('myCtrl',["$scope",function($scope){
    $scope.getVal=function(buttonClicked){
        // buttonClicked contains the button name which is clicked
        console.log(buttonClicked);
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Bootstrap is just a CSS library that makes things look pretty; it doesn't change the behavior of any browser elements. By default, HTML `<button>` tags aren't meant to be form elements that represent data, so `ng-model` doesn't know how to attach to them. If you want a radio button group to work with `ng-model`, you'll need to use the [radio button directive in UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/buttons), or some other similar directive.